# Android Create Directory to device

Tags: android, file, directory

I use the following to check if a directory exists and if it doesn't it then creates it

```
    final String appPath = String.format("%s/DataFiles", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            File f = new File(appPath);
            if(f.exists() && f.isDirectory()){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DOES NOT Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            f.mkdir();
```

This works fine on my S3 that has a sd card inserted

When I try it on anither phone that doesnt have an sd card in it recognises that the directory doesnt exists and then doesnt create the directory

Any ideas whats wrong

Mark

BTW I have tried inserting an sd card but doesn't make a difference it still doesn't create directory.

Comment: Which phone did you try?

Comment: Something different: your if/else is not complete because it could exist and be a file. So you have to add one more else. Further you better test with `f.getParentFile().canWrite()`.

Comment: i have installed it on galaxy s3 and samsung tab 3 and works fine both running jellybean tried to install on moto E running kitkat and it wont create directory. have write permissions set ok it detect fine if directory is there or not but wont create directory if not there. if i toast the apppath it says its emulated/storage/0/

Comment: I have also removed sd card from S3 and Tab3 and it works perfect it just the moto E

Answer (score 0):

Before any operation you need to check if external storage is available.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal
if sd-card is not available or is not available for writing you need to use device storage:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal